# python multiprocessing Pool in Cluster

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, pool

I am using the following code (example) to do parallel processing in a cluster.
It runs perfectly in the cluster using all available cores in a Node just by typing:
python test.py

```
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    import glob
    from astropy.io import fits

    def read(files):
        data=fits.open(files)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        files= glob.glob("*.fits*")
        nfiles = len(files)
        pool = Pool()                       
        pool.map(read, files)
```

However, when I submit the batch job using 
srun -N 1 python test.py
It seems to use only 1 core not all the available cores in that node.
What should I change to distribute nfiles in a node among all the cores such that each core will get nfiles/ncores.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are specifying `-N 1` which means 1 node is assigned to the call `python test.py`. Also, the default value for another flag `-n` is 1. Change it to `-N nnodes` where `nnodes` equals the number of nodes that you intend to run your script on and specify `-n ncores` where `ncores` is equal to the number of cores on each node. If your nodes are heterogenous, then you may run the risk of setting up more tasks than cores on each node or idle cores on nodes.

For more documentation on the above flags see [here](https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html).

Comment: I also used srun -N 1 -n 24 python test.py but it seems all the files (nfiles) are going to all cores (not distributed i.e total=nfile*ncores) and the run time was even longer.